# Como inserir quebra de linha em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, quebras-de-linha

Meu código possui um Textarea, nele eu mando algumas mensagens, porém quando pulo uma linha, ao receber esta mensagem a quebra de linha é ignorada

atualmente eu uso o seguinte comando na minha função javascript para que force a quebra de linha

```
mensagem = document.getElementById("id_textarea_conteudo").value.replace("\n","<br>");
```

Porém não resolveu meu problema, porque  ao invez de quebrar todas as linha puladas da mensagem, esta quebrando apenas a primeira linha.

exemplo:

```
teste teste teste teste
```

esta retornando da seguinte maneira

```
teste
teste teste teste
```

e eu preciso que retorne

```
teste 
teste
teste
teste
```

tem alguma maneira de resolver este problema que estou tendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É com `\n` mesmo. `<br>` é para quebrar linhas no HTML, não nos valores dos inputs.

```js
const str = 'texto\ntexto\ntexto\ntexto'
document.getElementById('ta').value = str
const a = document.getElementById('ta').value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')
document.getElementById('dv').innerHTML = a
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" style="height: 100px">
</textarea>

<div id="dv"></div>
```

---

**Edit**

Se você quiser recuperar o valor de um `textarea` e utiliza-lo no html, você tem que fazer o replace usando expressão regular para substituir todas as ocorrências de `\n`, não só a primeira:

```
const texto = document.getElementById('minhaTextarea').value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
```

Comment: executei um teste dessa maneira é consegui fazer funcionar, o que estava faltando era, corrigir a expressão regular utilizada, ao inves de replace("\n","<br>") mudei para replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br/>') e deu certo.